# How can I force convert a lead once in 'qualified' stage?

Tags: trigger, lead-conversion, automation

We want our leads to be automatically converted to account/contact (no oppty) once it's status changes to "Qualified"

The only way I can think of is an Lead After Trigger.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

That's correct a trigger on lead after update(and/or after insert), check at the doc [How to convert a lead by code](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_convertLead.htm)

```
Lead myLead = new Lead(LastName = 'Fry', Company='Fry And Sons');
insert myLead;

Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
lc.setLeadId(myLead.id);

LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());
```